# How do I make the first radio button option of a list of inputs selected by default on Shopify?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, shopify, liquid

I'm creating a Shopify theme in which product options are made of radio buttons rather than dropdown selects. For example, the code for the product color option is:

```
{% for value in option.values %}
  {% assign radio_id = 'option-' | append: option_name | append: '-' | append: value | handleize %}
  <input class="variant-radio" id="{{ radio_id }}" type="radio" name="{{ option_name }}" value="{{ value }}" {% if value == selected %}checked{% endif %}>
  <label for="{{ radio_id }}">
    {{ value }}
  </label>
{% endfor %}
```

How do I make the first option as the default selected color? If I remove the `{% if value == selected %}` and `{% endif %}` around `checked`, it only sets the last option as selected by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit the `if value == selected` code and use jquery:

`$("input[type=radio].variant-radio:first").attr('checked', true);`

Comment: Though it is an accepted solution, this is not the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `{% forloop.index %}` to get the current [index](https://shopify.dev/docs/liquid/reference/objects/for-loops#forloop-index) of your cycle from within the "for" loop.

So you can use something like that:

```
{% for value in option.values %}
  ...
  <input type="radio"{% if forloop.index == 1 %} checked="checked"{% endif %}>
  ...
{% endfor %}
```